# Android build failed

Tags: android, command-line, build, opensuse

I have downloaded Android SDK Tools. Unpack the file and then run these commands in directory tools

1. `./android update sdk --no-ui`
2. `./android create project --target 1 --name MyApp --path ./MyApp --activity MyAppActivity --package com.example.myapp`
3. `cd MyApp`
4. `ant debug`

and get this error:

> BUILD FAILED
>   /home/lived/devel/android/tools/MyApp/build.xml:90: The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/lived/devel/android/tools/ant/build.xml:108: taskdef A class needed by class com.android.ant.SignApkTask cannot be found: com.android.ant.SignApkTask
>        using the classloader AntClassLoader[/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/anttasks.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/common.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/guava-tools.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/sdklib.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/layoutlib_api.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/commons-compress-1.0.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/httpmime-4.1.1.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/dvlib.jar:/home/lived/devel/android/tools/lib/manifmerger.jar]

System information:

```
lived@dama:~> cat /etc/SuSE-release
openSUSE 12.2 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12.2
CODENAME = Mantis

lived@dama:~> java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (suse-3.16.1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

lived@dama:~> javac --version
javac (SUSE Linux) 4.7.1 20120723 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 189773]
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

lived@dama:~> ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 23 2012
```

am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by installing  package java-1_7_0-openjdk-devel. Before I only installed patters-openSUSE-devel_java.